# Setting active profile from environment variable in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring

I need to access the application context in my postconstruction hook. Is this possible and how can it be done programatically?

```
public final void systemSetup() throws Exception {
  // I would like to set active profile here so I need the context.
  context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(APP_ENV.toLowerCase()); 
  PrintVariables();
  InitializeLimeService();
  InitializeSGCSClient();
}
```

Please advice.

Comment: Although you shouldn't be setting the active profile like that, you should do it before the context is initialized. You can simply get access by adding an field of the `ApplicationContext` type and put `@Autowired` on it.

Comment: I tried that and it seems to give me access unfortunatly I really need access before dependency injection happens how can I do this? Im using a web.xml config but this does not allow me to use env vars to set the active profile. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: yes it does. Set a system property `spring.profiles.active` and it will be used. Else create an `ApplicationCOntextInitializer` which sets the active profile based on what you want (but judging from your code it basically is a constant so not sure why you would need that).

Comment: system property like system wide or for the java env?

Comment: It does actually work! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up createing a ApplicationContextInitializer like so.

```
package com.realitylabs.spa.tool;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

/**
 * @author Pablo Karlsson
 *
 * ConfigurableApplicationContextInitializer sets the spring profile
 * before application initialization so we can use dependency injection
 * based on profile. This allows us to mock services like SGCSClientService
 * In development mode.
 */
public class ConfigurableApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

  @Override
  public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {

    String APP_ENV = System.getenv("APP_ENV");

    if(APP_ENV == null) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Please set APP_ENV to production or development");
    }

    APP_ENV = APP_ENV.toLowerCase();

    if(!APP_ENV.equals("development") && !APP_ENV.equals("production")) {

      throw new RuntimeException("Please set APP_ENV to production or development");
    }

    context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(APP_ENV);
  }
}
```

I added the following rows to my web.xml

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.realitylabs.spa.tool.ConfigurableApplicationContextInitializer</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

This works really well. Thanks for the help!